# Pig Script - Min, Avg, Max

Tags: apache-pig

Let us say I have these in a file ...

```
    1
    2
    3
```

Using a Pig Script, how can I get this (number, minimum, mean, maximum in each line) ?

```
    1,1,2,3
    2,1,2,3
    3,1,2,3
```

Please let me know the Pig Script.  I am able to get the MIN, AVG, MAX using Pig built in functions, but am not able to get them all in each line.

Thanks
Naga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my simple solution for the problem.
I had the following numbers as input,

> temp2.txt

```
1
2
3
4
5
.
.
16
17
18
19
20
```

I followed these steps,

1]loaded the data from the file

2]Then grouped all the data

3]Found Average,Minimum,Maximum from the grouped data

4]Then foreach value in loaded data generated data and the minimum , maximum and average values.

The code is as follows,

```
grunt> data = load '/home/temp2.txt' as (val);
grunt> g = group data all; 
grunt> avg = foreach g generate AVG(data.val) as a;
grunt> min = foreach g generate MIN(data.val) as m;
grunt> max = foreach g generate MAX(data.val) as x;
grunt> values = foreach data generate val,min.m,max.x,avg.a; 
grunt> dump values;
```

The following is the output,

> Output

```
(1,1.0,20.0,10.5)
(2,1.0,20.0,10.5)
(3,1.0,20.0,10.5)
(4,1.0,20.0,10.5)
(5,1.0,20.0,10.5)
(6,1.0,20.0,10.5)
(7,1.0,20.0,10.5)
(8,1.0,20.0,10.5)
(9,1.0,20.0,10.5)
(10,1.0,20.0,10.5)
(11,1.0,20.0,10.5)
(12,1.0,20.0,10.5)
(13,1.0,20.0,10.5)
(14,1.0,20.0,10.5)
(15,1.0,20.0,10.5)
(16,1.0,20.0,10.5)
(17,1.0,20.0,10.5)
(18,1.0,20.0,10.5)
(19,1.0,20.0,10.5)
(20,1.0,20.0,10.5)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`TOBAG`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/TOBAG.html) built-in UDF to get your fields into a bag, and then you can use the `MIN`, `AVG`, and `MAX` functions on that bag.  You should have no trouble using all three summary functions on a single record.